# Is this correct way of replying with available dates for an interview

Tags: word-choice, email, synonyms

I trying to reply for an email with my available dates and times for the interview

"I'm available on the dates and times mentioned below. Please let me know if any of them works for you."

Does this suffice (or) Is there a better/shorter way I can reply?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Clear and concise. Don't try to shroud it in obfuscating mystery by attempting to restructure its elegance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be better to mention it as your *convenience* rather than *availability*. Here is an example:

> It would be convenient for me to have the interview on 5th, 10th or
>   18th of August. Do please check your calendar and inform me when it
>   could be scheduled.

Here you may mention the dates in any form respective to the proximity.

Comment: Probably should add a "your lordship" or two in there for good measure.

Comment: @augurar lol that is hilarious

Answer (score 1):

Replying to a solicitation for a job interview should be done in the context of making such an interview convenient for the prospective ***employer***, not the ***employee***. Further, any reply that narrowed opportunities to only a handful of dates can create the notion that interviewing for this prospective job is something you'll do if nothing better or more important appears on your schedule. On that basis, I would respectfully disagree with the selected answer and submit the following:

> "I will make every effort to accommodate your earliest convenience for
>   an interview. My schedule shows that I have no conflicts on August
>   16th, 18th, and 19th."

The objective is two-fold: Be gracious and deferential to the prospective employer, and provide specific dates for which scheduling would be simplest.